# Allow grouping with NA in aggregate function

Tags: r, aggregate

Here is dummy data

```
temp.df <- data.frame(count = rep(1,6), x = c(1,1,NA,NA,3,10), y=c("A","A","A","A","B","B"))
```

When I apply aggregate as given below:

```
aggregate(count ~ x + y, data=temp.df, FUN=sum, na.rm=FALSE, na.action=na.pass)
```

I get:

```
   x y count
1  1 A     2
2  3 B     1
3 10 B     1
```

However, I would like the following output:

```
   x  y count
1  NA A     2
2  1  A     2
3  3  B     1
4 10  B     1
```

Hope it makes sense.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with `temp.df$x[is.na(temp.df$x)] <- 'NA'`

Comment: Thanks, I tried something similar and it does work if I replace NAs with some string or a number like -1

Comment: If you want `NA` to behave as `NA`, then HongOoi's answer may be what you wanted, which will convert the `x` to `factor` class.  In my solution, it converts `x` to 'character' class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `addNA` to treat `NA` as a distinct level of x.

```
> temp.df$x <- addNA(temp.df$x)
> aggregate(count ~ x + y, data=temp.df, FUN=sum, na.rm=FALSE, na.action=na.pass)
     x y count
1    1 A     2
2 <NA> A     2
3    3 B     1
4   10 B     1
```

Answer (score 2):

One option may be to convert the `NA` to character `"NA"` (but I am not sure why you need the missing values)

```
temp.df$x[is.na(temp.df$x)] <- 'NA'
aggregate(count ~ x + y, data=temp.df, FUN=sum, na.rm=FALSE, na.action=na.pass)
#   x y count
#1  1 A     2
#2 NA A     2
#3 10 B     1
#4  3 B     1
```